# Delete Filegroup and File from database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, database-partitioning, filegroup

This is my database structure:

- 4 filegroups: PRIMARY, FileGroup201708, FileGroup201709, FileGroup201710
- 4 files: File1.mdf, File201708.ndf, File201709.ndf, File201710.ndf

This is the partition scheme and Function:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [MyFunction](datetime) 
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (N'2017-08-01T00:00:00.000', N'2017-09-01T00:00:00.000', N'2017-10-01T00:00:00.000')

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [MyScheme] 
AS PARTITION [MyFunction] TO ([PRIMARY], [FileGroup201708], [FileGroup201709], [FileGroup201710])
```

All table in the database are partitioned.

Well, I decided to delete all data for 201708 period, first I perform :

```
TRUNCATE TABLE MyTable WITH (PARTITIONS (partition_number))
```

for all table. After this operation there isn't any data for partition in table.

```
SELECT
    p.partition_number, fg.name, p.rows, OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id)
FROM
    sys.partitions p
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units au ON au.container_id = p.hobt_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.filegroups fg ON fg.data_space_id = au.data_space_id
WHERE
    p.object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyTable')
```

The query above give me 0 rows for the specific filegroup.

Now I want to delete the file and the filegroup, when I try to delete the file there is no problem, but when I try to delete a filegroup, I get an error from SQL Server:

> The filegroup 'FileGroup201708' cannot be removed because it is not empty

I checked if there are some indexes in that filegroup using this query:

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(i.[object_id]) AS [ObjectName],
    i.[index_id] AS [IndexID],
    i.[name] AS [IndexName],
    i.[type_desc] AS [IndexType],
    i.[data_space_id] AS [DatabaseSpaceID],
    f.[name] AS [FileGroup],
    d.[physical_name] AS [DatabaseFileName]
FROM 
    [sys].[indexes] i
INNER JOIN 
    [sys].[filegroups] f ON f.[data_space_id] = i.[data_space_id]
INNER JOIN 
    [sys].[database_files] d ON f.[data_space_id] = d.[data_space_id]
INNER JOIN 
    [sys].[data_spaces] s ON f.[data_space_id] = s.[data_space_id]
WHERE 
    OBJECTPROPERTY(i.[object_id], 'IsUserTable') = 1
ORDER BY 
    OBJECT_NAME(i.[object_id]), f.[name], i.[data_space_id]
```

But all rows have in the column "FileGroup", PRIMARY filegroup. Can anyone give some suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
GO
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION MyFunction() MERGE RANGE (31);
GO
ALTER DATABASE [MYDB] REMOVE FILE [File31]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [MYDB] REMOVE FILEGROUP [FileGroup_31]
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

First `DBCC Shrinkfile` for truncate,
Then remove the filegroup from the partition scheme then

```
ALTER DATABASE [db name] `REMOVE FILE` [file name]
GO


ALTER DATABASE [db name] `REMOVE FILEGROUP` [FileGroup201708]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (not being able to delete filegroups).
What I did was:

1. DROP TABLE MyTable
2. DROP Files inside those FileGroups

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE MyDB
   REMOVE FILE logical_file_name_found_in_db_properties_in_files_section`
   ```
3. DROP PARTITION SCHEME MyScheme
4. DROP PARTITION FUNCTION MyFunction
5. DROP FileGroups

Comment: Please provide more detail , paste some code so the one who asks could understand and get use of your answer

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution:

```
ALTER TABLE Fisier DROP column Fisier
GO
ALTER TABLE Fisier SET (FILESTREAM_ON="NULL")
GO
ALTER TABLE FisierRev DROP column Fisier
GO
ALTER TABLE FisierRev SET (FILESTREAM_ON="NULL")
GO
ALTER TABLE Contract DROP column Fisier
GO
ALTER TABLE Contract SET (FILESTREAM_ON="NULL")
GO

USE gestiunea_inan_19Rebut
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'inan_magazin5_fs', EMPTYFILE)
GO


EXEC sp_filestream_force_garbage_collection @dbname = N'gestiunea_inan_19Rebut'

ALTER Database gestiunea_inan_19Rebut REMOVE FILE inan_magazin5_fs
GO
ALTER Database gestiunea_inan_19Rebut REMOVE FILEGROUP FILESTREAMGROUP
GO


IF COL_LENGTH('Fisier','Fisier') IS NULL
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE Fisier ADD Fisier [varbinary](max)   NULL
END
GO
IF COL_LENGTH('FisierRev','Fisier') IS NULL
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE FisierRev ADD Fisier [varbinary](max)   NULL
END
GO

IF COL_LENGTH('Contract','Fisier') IS NULL
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE Contract ADD Fisier [varbinary](max)   NULL
END
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

This procedure is not working on my Database:
SHRINK EMPTYFILE: OK
Remove file :  OK
Remove filegroup :  KO
The filegroup FG_201510 cannot be removed because it is not empty.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).